# Normal layout for HVGA and WVGA (hdpi) but different result

Tags: android

i have tried XML normal layout for HVGA and  WVGA (hdpi), but when i try it in AVD different result. any one can help me? thanks

Comment: Please be specific. What is the xml code? What are you expecting and what do you get?

Comment: i used layout with dip,  for example: android:layout_width="300dip"
  android:layout_height="300dip"

Answer (score 5):

To target HVGA 320*480 use:

```
layout-normal-mdpi
```

At the same time to support WVGA screens and i.e. Galaxy Tab you need:

```
layout-normal-hdpi
```

folders.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/practices/screens_support.html). 
300dip in HVGA(320x480) is 300px 
300dip in WVGA800(480x800) is 450px 
So they got different results.

Comment: how can you know 320x480 is 300px? there is no information about that in http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: In Table 1. HVGA(320x480） is mdpi, which is 160 density. According to the definition of "Density-independent pixel (dp)" in the page, 300dpi in HVGA(320x480) is 300px.

Answer (score 0):

HVGA is normal screen and WVGA is large screen but both mdpi so make different folder named with qualifiers.
Please find more from here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers